# Show read-only rooms calendar in Exchange 2013 OWA did't work

Tags: exchange-2013, outlook-web-app, calendar

We have recently migrated to Exchange 2013 from Exchange 2007 and everything seemed to be ok. Users can access their mailboxes via Outlook and OWA,it was tested and working.

However we have several conference rooms with calendars, and calendar information was shown on our SharePoint portal pages.
As I remember, for these rooms we gave all users access only to mailbox folder "Calendar", and not to the whole mailbox.
We would like to achieve the same result (give all users rights to view Calendar information on rooms mailboxes), without giving them full access to the room.
And we would like to show it on web-page using OWA Web Parts.
Now about our problem:

On Exchange 2007 we have room with calendar, e.g. room_2306. 
It can be shown on SharePoint with URL
https://ex01.example.org/owa/ROOM_2306@example.org/?cmd=contents&part=1&module=calendar&view=Weekly

And it works without giving all users permissions to the room_2306 mailbox.
If I try to open full OWA by https://ex01.example.org/owa/ROOM_2306@example.org/ I will get message that I do not have rights. It's OK.

Now we try to do the same in Exchange 2013
We created new room

```
New-Mailbox -Database “mbdb_ex13” –Name Room_2013 –OrganizationalUnit “example.org/ResourceAccounts” -DisplayName “Room2013” –Room
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "Room2013:\Calendar" -User Default -AccessRights LimitedDetails
Set-MailboxFolderPermission -identity "Room2013:\Calendar" -User Anonymous -AccessRights LimitedDetails
```

But we can't open it in OWA, unless we give full permissions to the mailbox

```
Add-MailboxPermission -identity "Room2013" -User "Domain Users" -AccessRights FullAccess
```

Error message in OWA is "You don't have permission to open this mailbox."
Even if we use only calendar part in URL.
URLs are still supported in 2013: technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt574711(v=exchg.150).aspx

Is there any way to display Room calendar in OWA Web Part without giving full access to the mailbox?